# Creating a data frame named after values from another data frame

Tags: python

I have a data frame containing three columns, whereas col_1 and col_2 are containing some arbitrary data:

```
data = {"Height": range(1, 20, 1), "Col_1": range(2, 40, 2), "Col_2": range(3, 60, 3)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    Height  Col_1  Col_2
0        1      2      3
1        2      4      6
2        3      6      9
3        4      8     12
4        5     10     15
5        6     12     18
6        7     14     21
7        8     16     24
8        9     18     27
9       10     20     30
10      11     22     33
11      12     24     36
12      13     26     39
13      14     28     42
14      15     30     45
15      16     32     48
16      17     34     51
17      18     36     54
18      19     38     57
```

and another data frame containing height values, that should be used to segment the Height column from the df.

```
data_segments = {"Section Height" : [1, 10, 20]}
df_segments = pd.DataFrame(data_segments)

   Section Height
0               1
1              10
2              20
```

I want to create two new data frames, `df_segment_0` containing all columns of the initial  `df` but only for `Height` rows within the first two indices in the `df_segments`. The same approach should be taken for the `df_segment_1`. They should look like:

```
df_segment_0
   Height  Col_1  Col_2
0       1      2      3
1       2      4      6
2       3      6      9
3       4      8     12
4       5     10     15
5       6     12     18
6       7     14     21
7       8     16     24
8       9     18     27

df_segment_1
    Height  Col_1  Col_2
9       10     20     30
10      11     22     33
11      12     24     36
12      13     26     39
13      14     28     42
14      15     30     45
15      16     32     48
16      17     34     51
17      18     36     54
18      19     38     57
```

I tried the following code using the `.loc` method and added the suggestion of C Hecht to create a list of data frames:

```
df_segment_list = []
    
try:
    for index in df_segments.index:            
        df_segment = df[["Height", "Col_1", "Col_2"]].loc[(df["Height"] >= df_segments["Section Height"][index]) & (df["Height"] < df_segments["Section Height"][index + 1])]
        df_segment_list.append(df_segment)
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Try-except is used only to ignore the error for the last name entry since there is no height for index=2. The data frames in this list can be accessed as C Hecht:

```
df_segment_0 = df_segment_list[0]

   Height  Col_1  Col_2
0       1      2      3
1       2      4      6
2       3      6      9
3       4      8     12
4       5     10     15
5       6     12     18
6       7     14     21
7       8     16     24
8       9     18     27
```

However, I would like to automate the naming of the final data frames. I tried:

```
for i in range(0, len(df_segment_list)):
    name = "df_segment_" + str(i)
    name = df_segment_list[i]
```

I expect that this code to simply automate the `df_segment_0 = df_segment_list[0]`, instead I receive an error `name 'df_segment_0' is not defined`.

The reason I need separate data frames is that I will perform many subsequent operations using `Col_1` and `Col_2`, so I need row-wise access to each one of them, for example:

```
df_segment_0 = df_segment_0 .assign(col_3 = df_segment_0 ["Col_1"] / df_segment_0 ["Col_2"])
```

How do I achieve this?

EDIT 1: Clarified question with the suggestion from C Hecht.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all entries that are smaller than the current segment height in your segmentation data frame, here you go :)

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Height": range(1, 20, 1), "Col_1": range(2, 40, 2), "Col_2": range(3, 60, 3)})
df_segments = pd.DataFrame({"Section Height": [1, 10, 20]})


def segment_data_frame(data_frame: pd.DataFrame, segmentation_plan: pd.DataFrame):
    df = data_frame.copy() # making a safety copy because we mutate the df !!!
    for sh in segmentation_plan["Section Height"]:  # sh is the new maximum "Height"
        df_new = df[df["Height"] < sh]  # select all entries that match the maximum "Height"
        df.drop(df_new.index, inplace=True)  # remove them from the original DataFrame

        yield df_new


# ATTENTION: segment_data_frame() will calculate each segment at runtime!
# So if you don't want to iterate over it but rather have one list to contain
# them all, you must use list(segment_data_frame(...)) or [x for x in segment_data_frame(...)]

for segment in segment_data_frame(df1, df_segments):
    print(segment)
    print()

print(list(segment_data_frame(df1, df_segments)))
```

If you want to execute certain steps on those steps you can just use the defined list like so:

```py
for segment in segment_data_frame(df1, df_segments):
    do_stuff_with(segment)
```

If you want to keep track **and name the individual frames**, you can use a **[dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't 100% understand what you have in mind, but I hope that the following should help you in finding the answer:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Section Height': [20, 90, 111, 232, 252, 3383, 3768, 3826, 3947, 4100], 'df_names': [f'df_section_{i}' for i in range(10)]})
df['shifted'] = df['Section Height'].shift(-1)
new_dfs = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if np.isnan(row['shifted']):
        # Don't know what you want to do here
        pass
    else:
        new_df = pd.DataFrame({'heights': [i for i in range(int(row['Section Height']), int(row['shifted']))]})
        new_df.name = row['df_names']
        new_dfs.append(new_df)
```

The content of new_dfs are dataframes that look like this:

```
    heights
0        20
1        21
2        22
3        23
4        24
..      ...
65       85
66       86
67       87
68       88
69       89
[70 rows x 1 columns]
```

If you clarify your questions given this input, we could help you all the way, but this should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Edit: A small comment on using `df.name`: This is not really stable and if you do stuff like dropping a column, pickling/unpickling, etc. the name will likely be lost. But you can surely find a good solution to maintain the name depending on your needs.

Comment: Indeed, I get a list of data frames but they are not properly separated, as shown in my edited question. Furthermore, if I try to print out for example "df_section_7", the same error is reported, that "df_section_7" is not defined. Btw, which part of my question is unclear?

Comment: The print statement needs to refer to a defined object. You could do `print(new_dfs[0])` to get the first df created. Python doesn't know what `df_section_7` is since it is not an object. And what do you mean with properly seperated? Please clarify what you mean by providing the expected result.

Comment: So how would I define data frame objects named df_section_0 to df_section_8? It seems like the error from my initial code persists, in that I manage to separate the data frame into segments, but each segment is not saved as a data frame object that I can use afterwards. Hope that makes more sense?

Comment: Each DataFrame is saved as an object in the list new_dfs. You could alternatively make a dict by changing `new_dfs = []` to `new_dfs = {}` and `new_dfs.append(new_df)` to `new_dfs[row['df_names']] = new_df` which allows you to call them by their name: `print(new_dfs['df_section_7'])`.

Comment: I managed to access the created data frames the way you suggested. However, I would like to automate the whole process without naming each segment individually, as in the future the number of segments may vary. I updated my question for better problem clarification. Any idea how I can achieve this?